# Could not find bcrypt-3.1.12 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt

I installed the gem 'devise' within my project. After doing so I tried to migrate the db; however this seems to stop due to "Could not find bcrypt-3.1.12 in any of the sources". It tells me to run bundle install again, which doesn't seem to work. I have to mention that the project is running on docker.

I tried uninstalling the gem and installing it again, as well as deleting the gemfile.lock file. These failed too.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.7', '>= 5.0.7.1'
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.18', '< 0.6.0'
gem 'devise'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bcrypt', platforms: :ruby

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: what was your bundle version and ruby version?
`bundle -v` will tell you the version no

Comment: bundle version is 1.16.5 and ruby version is 2.4.4

Comment: Just remove `platforms: :ruby` statement and try again.

Comment: I removed it ran bundle install and bundle update, but when I try to migrate I get the same error

Comment: what was the output of `gem install bcrypt`

Comment: Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed bcrypt-3.1.12
WARNING:  Unable to pull data from 'http://gems.github.com': bad response Not Found 404 (http://gems.github.io/specs.4.8.gz)
1 gem installed

Comment: That is what I get

Comment: I am not sure why its fetching data from  `gems.github.com` ideally it should fetch from `https://rubygems.org`

Comment: Is there a way to tell it where to fetch from?

Comment: what is output of `gem sources`

Comment: run this `gem sources -a https://rubygems.org` to set gem source

Comment: I added it but it's still fetching from gems.github.com when installing the gem

Comment: use `gem install bcrypt --source https://rubygems.org/` 
to install bcrypt

Comment: let me know if it works

Comment: Doesn't work, I get the same error, it's still pulling from the wrong source

Comment: i am out of  idea 
if you have `tmate` `https://tmate.io/`  then share your terminal session  here will check it on terminal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188622/discussion-between-rahul-mishra-and-razvanusc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is got resolved by rebuilding the docker service

`docker-compose --build app`